# Javascript / Add class to element with interval

Tags: javascript, html, intervals

Javascript isn't my forte, so I'm looking for help : How would you write a function which add a Class to 3 elements with interval ?

```
 <ul>
   <li class="panel">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

The idea is to add an `.--active` class on the 1st item when document is ready and remove it after 2sec to add it to the 2nd item and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you could loop through the `li`'s using the `index`, and reset the index to 0 when you reach the last `li` element :

```
if( $('li.panel.active').index() == lis_count-1 )
    active_li_index  = 0;
else
    active_li_index++;
```

Hope this helps.

**jQuery solution:**

```js
$(function(){
   var lis_count = $('li.panel').length;
   var active_li_index = 0;
   
   setInterval(function(){
      if( $('li.panel.active').index() == lis_count-1 )
        active_li_index  = 0;
      else
        active_li_index++;
        
      $('li.panel.active').removeClass('active');
      $('li.panel').eq(active_li_index).addClass('active');
   }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.active{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="panel active">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

**Pure JS solution:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
   var lis = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('li.panel'));
   var lis_count = lis.length;
   var active_li_index = 0;
   
   setInterval(function(){
      var active_li = document.querySelector('li.panel.active');
      
      if( lis.indexOf(active_li) == lis_count-1 )
        active_li_index  = 0;
      else
        active_li_index++;
        
      active_li.classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelectorAll('li.panel')[active_li_index].classList.add('active');
   }, 1000);
}, false);
```

```css
.active{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="panel active">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I try to do but in Javascript (the jQuery tag was a mistake), but I'll keep this snippet just in case :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps. I've just added the pure js solution.

Comment: **Works like a charm!** Il will keep this snippet -
Next step : receive javascript training :)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```js
function showGarland () {
  var itemClass   = 'panel';
  var activeClass = '--active';
  var wait        = 2000; // 2 seconds
 
  function toggleActive (element, index, maxIndex) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     element.classList.add(activeClass);
      setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove(activeClass);
        if (index == maxIndex) {
          runLoop();
        }
      }, wait);
    }, wait * index);  
  }

  function runLoop () {
    var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName(itemClass);
 
    for (var index = 0; index < allItems.length; index++) {
      var element = allItems[index];
      toggleActive(element, index, allItems.length - 1);
    }
  }
  
  runLoop();
}

window.addEventListener('load', showGarland);
```

```css
.--active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
   <li class="panel">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you use jQuery you can do :

```
jQuery(() => { // callback when DOM is ready
  $('.panel1').addClass('active'); // add your class

  setTimeout(() => { // function that execute the callback after 2000ms (2s)
   $('.panel1).removeClass('active'); // remove your class active
  }, 2000);
});
```

you should use different class for your differents div

Comment: *since you use jquery* how do you know??

Comment: that was in the tags when I commented, but obviously edited, see revision : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44655812/revisions

Comment: Thanks for your answer Epitouille !
I don't use jQuery (don't know why it was tagged so) on this project, this is why I'm looking for a vanilla JS alternative to this kind of script.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load",function change(i=0){
  var els=document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  if(els[i-1]) els[i-1].classList.toggle("active");
  els[i].classList.toggle("active");
  if(i<els.length-1) setTimeout(change,2000,i+1);
});
```

You could use a recursive approach to iterate over the class elements slowly and toggle their active class...

Comment: Yep, it's the kind of approach I'm looking for. I am not sure to properly understand this syntax here but it helps me!
So, if I'm correct, it says 'add a class to .panel elements until i = numbers of .panel' but I'm not sure about the `(els[i-1])`

Comment: @alexis wollseifen thats to unactive the previous one

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, you need to call `toggleClass` with the index you want to start, The functions `addClass` and `removeClass` supports multiple elements and multiple classes.

```js
// Add class to element
// support multiple classes
function addClass(elements, className){
  // split classes 
  var classArray = className.split(' ');
  var els = [];
  
  // If element does not have length property
  if(elements.length == undefined)
   els[0] = elements
  else
   els = elements;
  
  for(e=0; e<els.length; e++){
   var element = els[e];
    for(i=0; i<classArray.length; i++){
      if(element.className.indexOf(classArray[i])==-1){
        element.className += ' ' + classArray[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

// Remove class to element
// support multiple classes
function removeClass(elements, className){
 var classArray = className.split(' ');
  var els = [];
  
  // If elements does not have length property
  if(elements.length == undefined)
   els[0] = elements
  else
   els = elements;
    
  for(e=0; e<els.length; e++){
   var element = els[e];
    for(i= 0; i<classArray.length; i++){
      element.className = element.className.replace(classArray[i], '').trim();
    }
  }
}

function toggleClass(index){ 
  // get active elements and remove active class
  removeClass(document.getElementsByClassName('active'), 'active');
  
  // add class to element at index
  addClass(document.getElementsByClassName('panel')[index], 'active');
  
  // test if index should increment or reset
  if(index<document.getElementsByClassName('panel').length - 1){
   index++;
  }else{
   index = 0;
  }
  
  // wait 2sec until execute toggleClass again
  setTimeout(toggleClass, 2000, index);
}

toggleClass(0);
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
   <li class="panel">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel active">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```

**Edit:** By the way beware with method `classList` since you'll need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <div class="hide">
 text
</div> -->
<ul id="Items">
   <li class="panel">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel hide">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel hide">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
<style>

.hide{  
    visibility: hidden;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 var listItems = $("#Items li");
// alert(listItems);
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li); 
    setInterval(function(){ 
 product.css( "visibility", "visible" );  
$(li).next().css( "visibility", "hidden" ); 
$(li).prev().css( "visibility", "hidden" );  
  
}, 2000);
});
});
</script>
```

The above one works fine for two elements, but for the third element its showing quickly without displayinh the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```js
function showGarland () {
  var itemClass   = 'panel';
  var activeClass = '--active';
  var wait        = 2000; // 2 seconds
 
  function toggleActive (element, index, maxIndex) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     element.classList.add(activeClass);
      setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove(activeClass);
        if (index == maxIndex) {
          runLoop();
        }
      }, wait);
    }, wait * index);  
  }

  function runLoop () {
    var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName(itemClass);
 
    for (var index = 0; index < allItems.length; index++) {
      var element = allItems[index];
      toggleActive(element, index, allItems.length - 1);
    }
  }
  
  runLoop();
}

window.addEventListener('load', showGarland);
```

```css
.--active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
   <li class="panel">Item 1</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 2</li>
   <li class="panel">Item 3</li>
 </ul>
```